# Getting panel width and height in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I want to draw a gradient to a canvas and add it to an AbsolutePanel, thus i need width and height of absolutePanel to define gradient vector. But event if I add AbsolutePanel to RootLayoutPanel (via the north-widget of a DockPanel, which width set to 100%) and call a method setGradient() after, i still get 0 for width and height. How can i get the dimensions of the panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getOffsetWidth()` and `getOffsetHeight(`) methods. The doc is here:

```
Gets the object's offset width in pixels. This is the total width of the object,
including decorations such as border, margin, and padding.
```

The methods are defined in UiObject, so common for all widgets.

Comment: Maybe you need to wait until it layouts. The easiest to check would be add some button and make gradient when it is pressed. If it works then, you should either set some timeout or run you gradient code in "some" event handler (onload maybe). You can also add Window.addResizeHandler() to recalculate gradient when window is resized.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, i guessed that i would have problems with getting dimensions, and now changed to CSS3 gradient :)